# Accessing more than one functions in C++ DLL from C# program

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I implemented two functions in Visual C++ DLL project. These functions will be called from C# program.
These are my functions in C++ DLL (not the actual implementation). mytest.cpp project.

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport)void print_DB(null *head)
    {
        /*print all nodes*/
        return;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport)void* add_node(void *head, int data)
  {
      /*Add node to data base*/
      return (head);
  }
}
```

My C# program is as follows.

```
namespace example
{
    class test
    {
        [DllImport("mytest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

        unsafe public static extern void* add_node(void *head, int data);
        unsafe public static extern void print_DB(void *head);

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*initilialization*/
            head = add_node(head, a) 
            head = add_node(head, b) 
            head = add_node(head, c) 
            printDB(head);
        }
    }
}
```

**I am able to use on function at a time**.  ie, If I comment print_DB() deceleration from C# program, add_node() functionality is working. If I commented add_node() function  print_DB() function is working. In this way both functions are giving the expected results.

**If I am using both functions together, the function which is declared at the end is giving error as below**. Invoking or not invoking the functions don't have any effect on the behavior.

> Could not load type 'ConsoleApplication2.Program' from assembly
>   'ConsoleApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'printDB' has no
>   implementation (no RVA).

where "ConsoleApplication2.Program" is the name of my C# program.

If I change the order of the functions deceleration, will get same error for the other function.

**These are my questions**

1)I am new to C# programming. my expectation is this functions should work irrespective of how many functions we declared in the C# program. Is this is a expected behavior?

2)If it not the expected behavior What am I doing wrong?

Comment: every importing function should have its own DllImport attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DllImport` line must be present before every imported function declaration, like so:

```
namespace example
{
    class test
    {
        [DllImport("mytest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        unsafe public static extern void* add_node(void *head, int data);

        [DllImport("mytest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        unsafe public static extern void print_DB(void *head);

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*initilialization*/
            head = add_node(head, a) 
            head = add_node(head, b) 
            head = add_node(head, c) 
            printDB(head);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Belanger.